# create variable paramteter for batch file in a forfiles?

Tags: batch-file

I want to execute the `load.cmd` file with the name of a file I have stored as a parameter. I can't seem to get this to work. It appears that the directories are all, correct (if I remove the call load.cmd it will at least display the list of items in the folder) but the error that returns says that it can't find/recognize `load.cmd` as a valid file.

```
forfiles /p MappingFiles /C "cmd call load.cmd --graph data:@fname @path"
```

Is this a syntax error? or is this something that forfiles wasn't designed to do?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
forfiles /p MappingFiles /C "cmd call /c PATH\TO\load.cmd --graph data:@fname @path"
```

Replace `PATH\TO` with the actual full path to `load.cmd`.